Communication link error when Running a stored procedure that hits a a separate server via linked server
I’ve ran into an issue where we’re trying to execute a stored procedure from server A which fetches data in a variable from server B. The SP calls a linked server that exists on server A.
However, whenever we run this SP we receive “communication link failure” / “TDS stream errors” / “physical connection is unusable” errors. We initially believed this may have been a networking issue but we’re able to fetch data fine using simple Select * from linkedserver.DB.schema.table queries.
We’re unsure why this only fails when we fetch data from the linked server via SP.
Timeout settings have been set appropriately.
ERROR Messages:
`OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "myServer" returned message "Protocol error in TDS stream".
OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "myServer" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 65535, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].
OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "myServer" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 65535, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].
OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "myServer" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 64, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.`
Any ideas?

Posting the exact error message / error number would be helpful.
